# Extract from YAML values dynamically

Tags: yaml

Consider the following yaml file:

```yaml
topics:
  topicA:    
      bins:
        type: multi-bins
        map:
          FirstBin:
            source: value-field
            field-name: ServiceID
          SecondBin:
            source: value-field
            field-name: ServiceID            
    message-transformer:
      class: com.aerospike.connect.inbound.transforms.TombstoneMessageTransformer
      params:
        shouldDeleteOnNull: "FirstBin, SecondBin"
  topicB:
    ...
```

As you can see there duplication between the `topics.<topic-name>.bins.map.keys` and `topics.<topic-name>.message-transformer.params.shouldDeletedOnNull`

Is there a way to extract the values dynamically? I want to send to `shouldDeleteOnNull` all the keys of `topics.<topic-name>.bins.map`

Note: I don't want to create an env variable for that and use Yaml anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML is not a programming language. It doesn't let you *extract* anything and it doesn't let you *send* anything, because it does not provide you with any kind of actions or processing instructions.

While you can reference nodes multiple times with anchors, that doesn't help you here because you would need to concatenate values, which is not something that is possible in YAML. A solution that would work looks like this (shortened for clarity):

```yaml
map:
  &a FirstBin:
     source: value-field
     field-name: ServiceID
  &b SecondBin:
     source: value-field
     field-name: ServiceID
shouldDeleteOnNull: [*a, *b]
```

As you can see, I needed to make `shouldDeleteOnNull` a sequence rather than a scalar to make this work. This does not seem like much of an improvement.

Anything more sophisticated would need to be implemented in the code loading the file and therefore does not make sense to be discussed in a pure YAML context.